# How to change authenticate method: Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, login

I have create my NewLoginPost Controller action with extends LoginPost
in the execute function i call to authenticate method where i pass (email, password).
    `$customer = $this->customerAccountManagement->authenticate($identifier, $login['password']);`
 In the authentification a had this

```
public function authenticate($customerId, $password)
{
    $customerSecure = $this->customerRegistry->retrieveSecureData($customerId);
    $hash = $customerSecure->getPasswordHash() ?? '';
    if (!$this->encryptor->validateHash($password, $hash)) {
        $this->processAuthenticationFailure($customerId);
        if ($this->isLocked($customerId)) {
            throw new UserLockedException(__('The account is locked.'));
        }
        throw new InvalidEmailOrPasswordException(__('Invalid login or password.'));
    }
    return true;
}`
```

Also i create customer attribute new_pass.
Where magento get password_hash field in db?

What i can do to CHANGE validation on standart password and password_hash field to my attribute (new_pass). Please help.

Comment: What do you exactly want? Do you want your custom password field and login user by it? or just want to override authenticate function as you ask in heading of your question?(Sorry I do have to ask in answer I do not have much privileg to comment). In my case I have to do login by Username(custom attribute) not email so I did override authenticate() function by giving {<preference type>} in di.xml. You can find this function in {Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement.php} file.